# Issue IDE warning if annotated member is not surrounded with a particular block

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a data structure which has members that are not thread safe and the caller needs to lock the resource for reading and writing as appropriate. Here's a minimal code sample:

```
class ExampleResource : LockableProjectItem {
    override val readWriteLock: ReadWriteLock = ReentrantReadWriteLock()

    @RequiresReadLock
    val nonThreadSafeMember: String = ""
}

interface LockableProjectItem {
    val readWriteLock: ReadWriteLock
}

fun <T : LockableProjectItem, Out> T.readLock(block: T.() -> Out): Out {
    try {
        readWriteLock.readLock().lock()
        return block(this)
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock()
    }
}

fun <T : LockableProjectItem, Out> T.writeLock(block: T.() -> Out): Out {
    try {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().lock()
        return block(this)
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock()
    }
}

annotation class RequiresReadLock
```

A call `ExampleResource.nonThreadSafeMember` might then look like this:

```
val resource = ExampleResource()
val readResult = resource.readLock { nonThreadSafeMember }
```

To make sure that the caller is aware that the resource needs to be locked, I would like the IDE to issue a warning for any members that are annotated with `@RequiresReadLock` and are not surrounded with a `readLock` block. Is there any way to do this in IntelliJ without writing a custom plugin for the IDE?

Comment: Is it ok if this is an *error* instead?

Comment: Sure, that might be even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is sort of a hack, but using [context receivers](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md) might work. I don't think they are intended to be used in this way though.

You can declare a dummy `object` to act as the context receiver, and add that as a context receiver to the property:

```
object ReadLock

class ExampleResource : LockableProjectItem {
    override val readWriteLock: ReadWriteLock = ReentrantReadWriteLock()

    // properties with context receivers cannot have a backing field, so we need to explicitly declare this
    private val nonThreadSafeMemberField: String = ""

    context(ReadLock)
    val nonThreadSafeMember: String
        get() = nonThreadSafeMemberField
}
```

Then in `readLock`, you pass the `object`:

```
fun <T : LockableProjectItem, Out> T.readLock(block: context(ReadLock) T.() -> Out): Out {
    try {
        readWriteLock.readLock().lock()
        return block(ReadLock, this)
    } finally {
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock()
    }
}
```

Notes:

- This will give you an error if you try to access `nonThreadSafeMember` without the context receiver:

  ```
  val resource = ExampleResource()
  val readResult = resource.nonThreadSafeMember //error
  ```
- You can still access `nonThreadSafeMember` without acquiring a read lock by doing e.g.

  ```
  with(ReadLock) { // with(ReadLock) doesn't acquire the lock, just gets the context receiver
      resource.nonThreadSafeMember // no error
  }
  ```

  But it's way harder to *accidentally* write something like this, which I think is what you are trying to prevent.
- If you call another function inside `readLock`, and you want to access `nonThreadSafeMember` inside that function, you should mark that function with `context(ReadLock)` too. e.g.

  ```
  fun main() {
      val resource = ExampleResource()
      val readResult = resource.readLock {
          foo(this)
      }
  }

  context(ReadLock)
  fun foo(x: ExampleResource) {
      x.nonThreadSafeMember
  }
  ```

  The context receiver is propagated through.

Comment: Thisis a great idea, thank you! Unfortunately, not having properties with backing fields seems to break my serialization mechanism, so, I need to find a workaround for that, but that's a thing I need to solve on my own. Cheers ;)

Comment: @vatbub I guess the name of the property matters? If you are on JVM, try changing the `@JvmName` of the backing field to the name of the property, and that of the context receiver property to something else. Just a shot in the dark though.

Comment: No, it is actually the context receivers breaking it: Since the context receiver is effectively compiled as a getter that takes an argument, Jackson-Databind no longer recognizes it as a property to serialize. I would therefore either need to serialize the private backing member under a different name (thus changing the file format) or change my api by renaming the public property.

Comment: But you're right, the thing with @JvmName might actually work. Let me try that :)

Comment: Turns out Jackson has a `@JsonProperty("customName")` annotation which takes care of that. Cheers :)